# Java#Selenium: How to get all cell values in dynamic div table that is not having tr/td and only having div tags?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-table

Please help me iterate through all the cell values of a div table. The columns of the table are dynamic, thus they will display or not depends on the logged in user type.

I am able to get the cell values of Sub-Total Column and Report Name column, by using below xpath:

```
//*[@id='MyExpenses']/div/div/div[count(preceding-sibling::div)+1 = 
count(ancestor::div/div[1]/div[.='Sub-Total']/preceding-sibling::div)+1]"))

//*[@id='MyExpenses']/div/div/div[count(preceding-sibling::div)+1 = 
count(ancestor::div/div[1]/div[.='                Report Name            ']/preceding-sibling::div)+1]
```

However, when I am trying the same for any other column for example: Start Date then web driver is returning me the values of Report Name column. I am trying below xpath for Start Date:

```
//*[@id='MyExpenses']/div/div/div[count(preceding-sibling::div)+1 = count(ancestor::div/div[1]/div[.=' Start Date            ']/preceding-sibling::div)+1]
```

I also tried getting the cell values by class name but, that is also not working for few columns, because the class name is different for column header and its cell values for example for Start Date class name is, 'start' for the header while it is, 'date' for cell values. Also, the End Date cell values are having the same class i.e. 'date', Thus the below xpath is also not returning the desired output:

```
WebElement pendigTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='MyExpenses']"));
String startDate = pendigTable.findElements(By.className("date")).getText();
```

**For User 1:**

```
<div style="width: 100%" class="tab pend active col-12" id="MyExpenses">                                   

<div class="title-table">

            <div class="report-name">                Report Name            </div>
            <div class="type">                Report Type            </div>
            <div class="start"> Start Date            </div>            
            <div class="end"> End Date            </div>       
            <div class="sub-total">Sub-Total</div>    
</div>
   <div class="data-table">
        <div class="report-name" data-title="Report Name :">
        <a href="/gorillapro/web/Expense/AddTransactionToReport?ExpenseId=743">T1</a>               
            </div>

                 <div class="type" data-title=" Report Type :">      CORPORATE</div>           
                 <div class="date" data-title="Start Date :">                6/1/2020            </div>
                 <div class="date" data-title="End Date :">                  6/30/2020           </div>
                 <div class="sub-total" data-title="Sub-Total :">            12.00            </div>            
            </div>        
   </div>
```

**For User 2**

```
<div style="width: 100%" class="tab pend active col-12" id="MyExpenses">                                   

<div class="title-table">

            <div class="report-name">                Report Name            </div>
            <div class="type">                Report Type            </div>
            <div class="sub-total">Sub-Total</div>  
            <div id="lblProjectNumber">                Job Number            </div>         
            <div class="start"> Start Date            </div>            
            <div class="end"> End Date            </div>       

</div>
   <div class="data-table">
        <div class="report-name" data-title="Report Name :">
        <a href="/gorillapro/web/Expense/AddTransactionToReport?ExpenseId=743">T1</a>               
            </div>

                 <div class="type" data-title=" Report Type :">      CORPORATE</div>   
                <div class="sub-total" data-title="Sub-Total :">            12.00            </div> 
                <div class="conf-number" data-title="Confirmation No. :">          1221                  </div>             
                 <div class="date" data-title="Start Date :">                6/1/2020            </div>
                 <div class="date" data-title="End Date :">                  6/30/2020           </div>

            </div>        
   </div>
```

Comment: Please add HTML code as text not image. Why do you use so complicated XPath ? Isn't it more convenient to use `//div[@class="report-name"]` for report, `//div[@class="sub-total"][1]` for sub-total... For the other columns, you have plenty of options, like `//div[@*[position()=1 or position()=2][contains(.,"tart")]]` for start-date, `//div[@class="end" or starts-with(@data-title,"End")]` for end date.

Comment: Alternatively it seems the elements are in the same order in both div (title and data table). You could use position indexes to select what you want. `//div[@class][parent::div[contains(@class,"table")]][1]`,`//div[@class][parent::div[contains(@class,"table")]][2]` and so on...

Comment: I have added the HTML code instead of the image in the question

The reason I am using such XPath is that:
1. There are multiple tables(e.g. My Expenses, UnPaid Expenses Approved Expenses) having the same columns Report Name, Sub-Total, etc. columns thus the same class name in all tables
2. Columns in the tables are dynamic, for one user Sub-Total can be the third column in MyExpenses table and for other user, it can be at fifth position
3. For some users, these tables have additional columns such as Job and/or Class.

Comment: OK for the code and for the position indexes which can't be used. However, even if there are multiple tables, you can do it in a simpler way. I've posted XPath which work for the 2 samples you've posted. If they failed because they're not enough specific, please add more details in your sample data (for eg, I see `Total Reimbursable` is no more present) to straighten the XPath. Also, the XPath you show us can't be used with your sample data since a div is missing. `//*[@id='MyExpenses']/div/div/div[count(...` should be `//*[@id='MyExpenses']/div/div[count(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These XPath are working fine with your sample data :

```
//div[@id="MyExpenses"]//div[@class="report-name"]
//div[@id="MyExpenses"]//div[@class="type"]
//div[@id="MyExpenses"]//div[@class="end" or starts-with(@data-title,"End")]
//div[@id="MyExpenses"]//div[@class="start" or starts-with(@data-title,"Start")]
//div[@id="MyExpenses"]//div[@class="sub-total"][1]
```

Note : `[1]` at the end of the last expression since another `div` with the same class exists ('Total Reimbursable'). Replace `[1]` with `[2]` to get it.